# getServletContext().getRealPath("/") omitting forward slash (/)

Tags: java, html, apache, servlets, filepath

I'm trying to upload a file from an HTML file input.

I am using Apache Commons FileUpload and the file uploads successfully. However, when I try storing the file path in my MySQL, it is storing it without file path code:

```
String uploadFolder = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
filePath = uploadFolder+"/"+fileName;
File uploadedFile = new File(filePath);
```

This is how I'm trying to store the file.

**sample filepath stored**

```
C:UsersLashDesktopworkspace3.metadata.pluginsorg.eclipse.wst.server.core    mp0wtpwebappsJavaECom/download doget.txt
```

Comment: Try to make your question and the title more clear...

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what this question is about, but the correct way to do the operations your posted code is doing is as follows:

```
File uploadFolder = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName(); // not sure what's going on here
File uploadedFile = new File(uploadFolder, fileName);
```

Comment: im sorry if its misleading, but the file is being stored in a path. when i extract that path and save it in mysql, it is ommitting the / character